# How to design a custom view and attach it to UIButton view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

Is there any way how to create a xib with custom view (UIImage placeholder and UILabel placeholder), then to load the xib, grab its UIView and to pass it to UIButton view? The thing is I need to implement menu icon from design where button label is at the very bottom of the menu icon. By default the label in UIButton appears in the center. Heard it's possible to design a custom view in xib, load and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the nib is wired up with an `IBOutlet` named `subView`,

```
subView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mySubview" 
                                           owner:self options:nil];
```

Now you can use the subview to construct your button.

Comment: What such nib file should contain? UIView with UIImage (for showing menu button icon as button background) and UILabel for showing text? Also, how to add loaded "subView" to UIButon then, via addSubView?

Comment: Easier: make the subview clickable with `touchesBegan:...`. Otherwise use `UIButtonTypeCustom` and you can add the subviews.

Comment: Thanks, was missing the part - "UIButtonTypeCustom" :) I hope enabling user interaction will pass touch events from subView to the UIButton. But could you give some more details about the first solution with touchesBegan?

Comment: Use your view as the button, but of type `UIView`. override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and use that as the button handler. You have to do any button animations yourself.